# How to keep session storage for all form inputs after submission?

Tags: javascript, html

How to save all the values from customer? I can only save first name and last name. Can I pass more than 2 inputs in set details? I tried adding date of birth that had input type text in dd/mm/yyyy format but the value was being shown as "undefined".

Java Script

```
function getDetails(){
    if (typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("firstName") !== null){
            document.getElementById("firstName").value = sessionStorage.getItem("firstName");
        }
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("lastName") !== null){
            document.getElementById("lastName").value = sessionStorage.getItem("lastName");
        }
    }
}

function setDetails(firstName, lastName) {
    if (typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
        sessionStorage.setItem("firstName", firstName);
        sessionStorage.setItem("lastName", lastName);
    }
}
```

HTML Code

```
<label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder= "Enter first name"  title="20 characters" />
    <br>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder= "Enter last name" class="field" required pattern="([A-z]){1,20}" title="20 characters" />
    <br>
    <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" maxlength="10" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"  pattern="\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}"/>
```

Comment: You ask about some date but no where is that shown in your question. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have added the html code as well

Comment: You still haven't provided a [mcve] ...

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work to set & get "dob" in cookie:

```
<html>
<body>
    <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" maxlength="10" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"  pattern="\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}"/>
    <button onclick = "setDateInCookie();">SetCookie</button>
    <button onclick = "getDateFromCookie();">GetCookie</button>
    <script>
    function setDateInCookie(){
        var myDate = document.getElementById("dob").value;
        if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
            sessionStorage["myDate"] = myDate;
    }

    function getDateFromCookie(){
        var myDate = document.getElementById("dob").value;
        if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
        {
            if (sessionStorage.getItem("myDate") !== null){
                document.getElementById("dob").value = sessionStorage.getItem("myDate");
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Future Note:** Avoid using input type "text" for input type "date". Use the exact input types for not getting any issues in future.

Comment: Input type text is the requirement of the task. I tried your method but it shows undefined instead of the date. I have also uploaded my html in the description.

Comment: I have edited the code above, It will set the cookie using 'setDateInCookie()' function and can retrieve that cookie using 'getDateFromCookie()' function from sessionStorage.